# my hadoop job 252 hours later died(tasks then killed)

Tags: hadoop

I had 81,068 tasks complete but then 11,799 failed and only 12 were killed.  They SEEM to all failed from

```
2013-09-10 03:07:36,316 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskInProgress: Error from  attempt_201308301539_0002_m_083001_0: Error initializing attempt_201308301539_0002_m_083001_0:
org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker$DiskErrorException: Could not find taskTracker/jobcache/job_201308301539_0002/work in any of the configured local directories
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator$AllocatorPerContext.getLocalPathToRead(LocalDirAllocator.java:389)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalDirAllocator.getLocalPathToRead(LocalDirAllocator.java:138)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker$TaskInProgress.localizeTask(TaskTracker.java:1817)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker$TaskInProgress.launchTask(TaskTracker.java:1933)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.launchTaskForJob(TaskTracker.java:830)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.localizeJob(TaskTracker.java:824)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.startNewTask(TaskTracker.java:1664)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.access$1200(TaskTracker.java:97)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker$TaskLauncher.run(TaskTracker.java:1629)
```

At this point, I am just looking for guidance on how I can debug this before I re-run this again.  For some reason out in the cluster, it looks like all the files are deleted though I thought hadoop M/R only deleted successfull task logs????

Anyone have some advice/ideas on how to debug this further?

It looks like all the default directories for map/reduce are used... /tmp/hadoop-hduser for my hduser.

I have seen stuff on /etc/hosts but then I don't get why 81,000 tasks succeeded before finally failing???

I am using the web interface to get some of this information of course and some logs where hadoopinstalled/logs

thanks,
Dean